# Electron.js webview silent print

Tags: javascript, printing, electron, silent

I need to find a solution to make ANY print from webview silent using `window.print()`

in Electron html file, I used :

```
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
webview.print({silent: true})
```

but the dialog printing box still popup, anyone can help me to find out what is my mistake in above code.

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
path = "your path/name file.pdf"

document.querySelector('webview').printToPDF({
    marginsType: 0,
    pageSize: 'A4',
    printBackground: true,
    printSelectionOnly: false,
    landscape: false
}).then(data => {
    fs.writeFile(path, data, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('Sucess');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).